# Gallai partition

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, coloring, ramsey-theory, extremal-graph-theory

Gallai partition for edge coloring Reminder:
If G is an edge-coloured complete graph on at least two
vertices without a rainbow triangle, there is a nontrivial partition $P$ of $V(G)$ satisfying:

(1) If $A,B \in P$ satisfy P $A \not= B$, then all edges with one end in A and the other in B have the same colour.

(2) The set of edges with ends in distinct blocks of $P$ has at most two colours.

I have no idea why it is correct.
i did not found any proof in english for this over the internet.
I did how ever find the original paper but it is written in Hungarian, and i do not know this language.

can someone explain in english why this statement is correct or at least share with me a link to some source in english?

Comment: http://www.math.u-szeged.hu/~hajnal/seminars/kombszem/cikkek/szemi_gallai_color.pdf

Comment: Also, [the original paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02020961.pdf) is in German, not Hungarian. Gallai does have papers in Hungarian (notably, the paper proving the Erdos-Gallai theorem on degree sequences) but there's no Hungarian version of this one, as far as I can tell.